# How to create HKey Property with dropdown list?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Using Delphi 2010, I am creating a component with a Registry Key property.
I would like the property to show a dropdown list of the values. What I have below, only shows numerical values.

```
published
    property Key: HKey read FKey write SetKey Default HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to TLama's answer, I think that the most Delphi-ish way would be simply to do

```
type
  TRegistryRootKey = (rkClassesRoot, rkCurentUser, rkLocalMachine,
    rkUsers, rkPerformanceData, rkCurrentConfig, rtDynData);

...

published
  property RootKey: TRegistryRootKey read FRootKey write FRootKey
    default rkLocalMachine;
```

and when it is time to use the value, do something like

```
procedure TMyClass.DoSomething;
const
  RootKeys: array[TRegistryRootKey] of DWORD = (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
    HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG, HKEY_DYN_DATA);
begin

  Windows.SomeAPIFunction(RootKeys[FRootKey]);

end;
```

Of course, you could make the `RootKeys` constant a private constant of the class if you need it in more than a single method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `HKEY` as the property data type, then you will have to write a custom property editor in order to make the property display a drop-down list of human readable names at design-time.  Andreas' answer is a better choice.